# Drawing a pie chart from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I'm struggling with creating a pie chart from a MySql table.

My table is like below

```
buy_trader    qty

 TKS3G  2069
 MSB1G  4417
 JKB6   4021
 FWS2   3507
 ASI1G  2578
 other  18228
```

I'm using following code to generate a pie chart from the table. Please help me with this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Highcharts Example</title>

 <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if (!$con) {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("offlinesurv", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM top_buy_trades");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['buy_trader'] . "\t" . $row['qty']. "\n";
  }

   mysql_close($con);
  ?> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">



 $(function () {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
   chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
     renderTo: 'container',
     plotBackgroundColor: null,
     plotBorderWidth: null,
     plotShadow: false
       },
     title: {
       text: 'Top Buy Traders'
        },
        tooltip: {
         pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
         percentageDecimals: 1
         },
         plotOptions: {
           pie: {
           allowPointSelect: true,
           cursor: 'pointer',
           dataLabels: {
           enabled: true,
           color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: 'green',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Broker share',
            data: [<?php echo $row ?>]
        }]
    });
 });

});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me with this.As I'm struggling with this from some time.

whats the wrong in this code please

Comment: I think you should place that <script src="highcharts.js"> above the function for starters..

Comment: @user1793864 I wrote a PHP library for Highcharts, might help you out... https://github.com/catchamonkey/phighcharts

Comment: off topic, but please be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions in PHP are deprecated. If at all possible, please switch to using the newer `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead.

Comment: *struggling* isn't really a description of a problem. what's exactly wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

The line that reads:

```
data: [<?php echo $row ?>]
```

is not in a loop. You need to generate your series of data for highcahrts from the mysql data by looping over all over the database results. At the moment that will generate a single line, and since it is outside of the PHP loop, it will be incorrect.

It should be something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo //more data into your series array into the JS code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the values like this. Try the below code,

Change your while loop into,

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $traders[] = array(
      'trader' => $row['buy_trader'],
      'qty'    => $row['qty']
   );
}
```

Then change your script to,

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Broker share',
            data: [
                    <?php

                      foreach($traders as $trader) {
                         echo "[".$trader['trader'].",". $trader['qty']."],";
                     }
                     ?>
            ]
        }]
```

Comment: I Changed as you said, but no luck in it. Please help me

Comment: Can you check your browser error console whether there is any error?

Comment: Timestamp: 3/13/2013 11:39:25 AM
Error: [Exception... "'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "onProgressChange"' when calling method: [nsIWebProgressListener::onProgressChange]"  nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)"  location: "native frame :: <unknown filename> :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 0"  data: no]   these types of errors are available there

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at article about preprocessing data http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing